# How can I use powershell 4.0 set-acl to allow the user to have the same security settings in newly created subdirectories?

Tags: windows, powershell, server

When I set user access via set-acl I can loop through all existing subfolders. How do I set it to include future subfolders created under the main folder?

Also... Once the access is set it only displays in 'Advanced' settings for the folders. The first security screen shows the user but shows no access rights.

This is in Windows Server 2012 R2.

```
$SubFolder = "name"
$UserName = "domain\" + $SubFolder
$Folder = "R:\User Files\" + $SubFolder + "\"

$Acl = Get-Acl $Folder
$Ar = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule($UserName,"FullControl","Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
#Get-Variable
Set-Acl -Path $Folder -AclObject $Acl

$Folder = Get-childItem $Folder
foreach ($TempFolder in $Folder)
{
    $Folder = $TempFolder.FullName
    $Acl = Get-Acl $Folder
    $Ar = New-Object    system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule($UserName,"FullControl","Allow")
    $Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
    #Get-Variable
    Set-Acl -Path $Folder -AclObject $Acl
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I feel this question is better to post not here, at Stackoverflow, but at another Stack Exchange community.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set your Inheritance and Propagation flags in order for it to affect files and folders within your target. Here's my typical template that I use when I'm working on setting up new ACLs for users:

```
$Rights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"FullControl" 

$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ObjectInherit,ContainerInherit"
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None 

$objType =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 

#Define the user's account using their samAccountName
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("samAccountName") 

$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($objUser, $Rights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) 

$objACL = Get-ACL "C:\Temp" 

$objACL.AddAccessRule($objACE) 

Set-ACL "C:\Temp" $objACL
```

The settings here will make future things inherit the settings that you define for the target folder.